# how to show only users who have previously chat with [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, chat

I have table user

```
**| username | password |**
     username    1234
     username1   1234
     username2   1234
```

and message

```
**| from_user_name | to_user_name | message |**
     username        username1      Hi      
     username        username2      Hi
     username1       username      reply
```

this is my SQL code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " .table_name. " WHERE to_user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."' OR from_user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."' GROUP BY from_user_name,to_user_name";
```

I login with (username) if there is a reply from (username1) it will show

```
username 1
username 1
username 2
```

I need to show like

```
username 1
username 2
```

Can you please advise me, Thank you all

Comment: *I login with (username) if there is a reply from (username1) it will show* I don't believe - shown result structure does not match to the table structure where you're taken all columns from.

Comment: @akina It shows username 1 two time.  picture here https://www.picz.in.th/image/show.qIw0Z2 . I don't know how to insert picture here

Comment: *It shows username 1 two time.* This is NOT the point which I have told about. I have pointed that you either have edited the output by deleting some columns or have shown the output of another query, not of posted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN to_user_name = $_SESSION['username']
                     THEN from_user_name
                     ELSE to_user_name
                     END AS responder
FROM message
WHERE $_SESSION['username'] IN (from_user_name, to_user_name);
```

or

```sql
SELECT to_user_name AS responder
FROM message
WHERE from_user_name = $_SESSION['username']
UNION 
SELECT from_user_name 
FROM message
WHERE to_user_name = $_SESSION['username']
```

Comment: if this query helps you, then u should put this answer mark as solved your problem

Comment: @FachryDzaky Thank you for warning me, and sorry for my mistake